# validação numeral em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou a tentar fazer a validação de uma form. o usuario só pode apenas instroduzir valores numerais.
Fiz da seguinte forma mas não esta a funcionar

```
function ValidateContactForm()
{
    var year = document.ContactForm.year;

  if (year.value == "")
{
    isNaN( document.myForm.edition.value)
    window.alert("Please enter year.");
    year.focus();
    return false;
}  
}
```

codigo em HTML

```
<body>
        <?php include 'addDataAdmin.php';?>
        <form name="ContactForm" action="addDataAdmin.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm();">
            ISBN:<input type="text" name="ISBN">
            Author's Name:<input type="text" name="Authorsname">
            Title:<input type="text" name="Title">
            Edition:<input type="number" name="edition">
            Year:<input type="number" name="year">

            Category:
            <select name="category" size="1">
                <option value="computing">Computing</option>
                <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
                <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            Publisher:<input type="text" name="publisher">
            Quantity-in-stock:<input type="number" name="quantityinstock">
            Price:<input type="number" name="price">
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" formaction="/upload.php">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o teu HTML?

Comment: Reeditei a resposta para uma função apenas validar os campos numéricos

Comment: coloquei alert na resposta

Comment: Obrigado Leo, testei e não funcionou depois vi que está faltando apenas um { no seu código mas de resto tudo certo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SCRIPT**

```
    function SomenteNumero(e){
      var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;   
        if((tecla>47 && tecla<58)) return true;
        else{
           if (tecla==8 || tecla==0) return true;
        else  
           alert ( "Este campo aceita apenas números.");
           return false;
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

> Nos inputs que devam aceitar somente números coloque:
>
> onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'

```
   <body>
        <?php include 'addDataAdmin.php';?>
        <form name="ContactForm" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
            ISBN:<input type="text" name="ISBN">
            Author's Name:<input type="text" name="Authorsname">
            Title:<input type="text" name="Title">
            Edition:<input type="number" name="edition" onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'>
            Year:<input type="number" name="year" onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'>

            Category:
            <select name="category" size="1">
                <option value="computing">Computing</option>
                <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
                <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
                <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            Publisher:<input type="text" name="publisher">
            Quantity-in-stock:<input type="number" name="quantityinstock" onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'>
            Price:<input type="number" name="price">
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" formaction="/upload.php">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Demonstração

```js
function SomenteNumero(e){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;   
    if((tecla>47 && tecla<58)) return true;
    else{
     if (tecla==8 || tecla==0) return true;
 else  
 alert ( "Este campo aceita apenas números.");
 return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="verificar" name="nome" size="2" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)">
```

Comment: oi Leo. eu editei e coloquei meu codigo HTML. nao sera mais eficaz fazer de outra forma do que estar a criar uma nova função?

Comment: oi Leo esta funcionando, o problema é que eu tenho dois input que vao fazer uso da função somenteNumero, o problema é que eu preciso de ter uma janela alert para cada um, e neste momento com a função somente Numero não esta funcionando

Comment: editei a resposta para atender suas condições

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa do Javascript para isso, basta ir no seu form e trocar o input para um tipo number(HTML5):

Exemplo:

```
 <input type="number" size="6" name="age" min="18" max="99" value="21" required />
```

Comment: Acho que vale um adendo de que é HTML5 :)

Comment: Opa! Vou editar

Comment: oi Lucas estive a tentar e de facto ajuda colocar este tipo de input. mas o problema é que esse input  permite voce colocar numero um a um atraves de umas setinhas no canto. mas eu tenho uma text box onde tenho que inserir preço de um produto ai esse input que voce sugeriu ja não faz aquilo que eu pretendo, ou mesmo para colocar anos, por exemplo tambem tenho uma text box em que tenho que colocar o ano em que o livro foi editado.

Answer (score 0):

Se for somente validar se é um numero valido, pode fazer assim tambem, parecido com o que voce fez.

Aceita tanto `int` quanto `float`, lembrando que `float` so vai funcionar com `.` tipo `10.28` para aceitar `,` já é outro problema.

```js
function valida() {
     var el = document.getElementById("ano");
     var str = el.value;
     var num = parseFloat(str);
      
      if(isNaN(num)){
        alert('Não é um número válido '+num);
      }else{
        alert('É um número válido!! '+num);
      }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="nome2" id="ano" value="">

<button type="button" onclick="valida()">OK</button>
```